# How to properly type Sequelize using Sequelize.define?

Tags: typescript, sequelize.js

My team is currently migrating to Typescript and we're having some trouble migrating our v6 Sequelize code. Unfortunately, we cannot use a class based approach so we're stuck with `sequelize.define`.

Currently our models look something like this:

```
export interface UserAttributes {
  id: number;
  createdAt: Date;
  updatedAt: Date;
  deletedAt: Date | null;
  email: string;
  name: string;
}

export type UserCreationAttributes = Omit<UserAttributes, 'id' | 'createdAt' | 'updatedAt' | 'deletedAt'>;
type UserSequelizeDefineAttributes = Omit<UserAttributes, 'id' | 'createdAt' | 'updatedAt' | 'deletedAt'>;

export interface UserInstance extends Model<UserAttributes, UserCreationAttributes>, UserAttributes {
  hashPassword: (password: string) => Promise<string>;
}

export default (sequelize: Sequelize, DataTypes: typeof SequelizeDataTypes) => {
  const User = sequelize.define<UserInstance, UserSequelizeDefineAttributes>(
    'user',
    {
      email: DataTypes.STRING,
      name: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    {
      tableName: 'user',
      paranoid: true,
      timestamps: true,
      freezeTableName: true,
    }
  ) as UserInstance & typeof Model & {
    new (values?: object, options?: BuildOptions): Model;
  };

  User.hashPassword = async function (password: string): Promise<string> {
    return await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);
  };

  return User;
}
```

I'd like to remove the cast after sequelize define if possible but not really sure how to best approach it. Is there a better way of setting up the model without using classes?